# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in Scanner

Tags: java

I want to scanner console and proceed what user input as a string, then scanner file which name is that string.

`public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      intro();
      System.out.print("input file name?");
      String inputfile = console.next();
      Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(inputfile));
   }`

But when I entered file name such as personality.txt, java keeps telling me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9. How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yea, you need to provide more information, for example the intro() method contents, the full stacktrace with corresponding line numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

tried your code but no exception occurred. not sure what causes that error but may be you can use 
String inputfile = console.nextLine();